# How do I print adjacent list in specific format without using the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I have an undirected weighted graph:

[image: graph]

I want to print an adjacent list in the following format:

```
0--> 1 --> 2
1 --> 0 --> 2 --> 3
2 --> 0 --> 1 --> 4
3 --> 1 --> 4
4 --> 2 --> 3 --> 5
5 --> 4 --> 6
6-->5
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nodes = 7;
    int graphList[nodes][nodes];

    for(int i = 0; i<nodes;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<nodes;j++){
            graphList[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    int n1, n2, weight;

    for(int j = 0; j<8;j++){
        cin>>n1>>n2>>weight;
        graphList[n1][n2]= weight;
        graphList[n2][n1]= weight;
    }

    cout<<"Adjacent list: \n";
    for(int i = 0; i<nodes;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<nodes;j++){
            if(graphList[i][j]!=0){
                cout<<i<<"-->"<<j<<endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This way I was able to get output like this:

```
 Adjacent list:
    0-->1
    0-->2
    1-->0
    1-->2
    1-->3
    2-->0
    2-->1
    2-->4
    3-->1
    3-->4
    4-->2
    4-->3
    4-->5
    5-->4
    5-->6
    6-->5
```

How can I print like the mentioned format, without using the C++ standard library?

**Note: It is an assignment, and so I cannot use the standard library as a requirement.**

Comment: Please no images of output.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It's an assignment and I am required to complete this without using STL.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE I am sorry I didn't understand your comment. Are you asking me to remove my output image from the question?

Comment: @ShakilMahmudShanto they are asking you to post the output as plain text rather than an image

Comment: On a side note: `int nodes = 7; int graphList[nodes][nodes];` is [not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/). `nodes` should be `const`, especially since you can't use `std::vector`.

Comment: So basically, you are currently streaming `i` and `endl` for each `j`, but you want those to stream only for each `i`? That's how you want to adjust your output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are able to output the adjacency list alphabetically by the first element, you can simply output the format as you desire with a flag within the inner loop of :

```
    cout<<"Adjacent list: \n";
    for(int i = 0; i<nodes;i++){
        bool flag = true;
        for(int j = 0; j<nodes;j++){
            if(graphList[i][j]!=0){
                if (flag) {
                    cout<<i<<"-->"<<j;
                    flag = false;
                }
                else {
                    cout<<"-->"<<j;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

In the if statement, if first inside it, then output the first element otherweise, output "-->" second element.

Comment: It might help if you actually showed what that should look like

Comment: It's almost working. Nodes(1,2,4) with more than 2 adjacent nodes are having an issue. The third node is printing in the next line.

Comment: @ShakilMahmudShanto I modified the answer

Comment: @PhilHuang Thanks a lot! It's working great now. I have marked your answer as correct.

Comment: @ShakilMahmudShanto Cool :)

Comment: Why use a flag?